# Windows Phone 8 Paused video doesn't Resume (audio does)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mediaelement

In my application i have a `fullscreen MediaElement` that reproduces a full screen video.

When i Pause the video i cannot resume it `(with MediaElement1.Play())` as only audio resumes.

It seems like the video is not being redrawn properly as i tried to put a `button` in front of it and if i `hold the button` (so i guess i'm force the mediaelement in background to redraw) 
the video starts showing up.

This seems to be confirmed by the fact that using :

```
Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
```

the video playback resumes properly even without the button exploit.

If anyone could help i would be very very grateful. Thanks a lot for reading and commenting.

Comment: I just wish to add that both mentioned exploit are not acceptable as: 1) the button needs to be pressed and 2) the FrameRateCounter diplays a ugly bar that i don't want my users to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem in another way.
I noticed that video resumes after clicking Play button twice, so I used DispatcherTimer to call MyPlayer.Play() for one more time a moment later

```
 DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
        dt.Tick += new EventHandler(Ticked);
    }

   private void Ticked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyPlayer.Play();
        dt.Stop();
    }
 private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyPlayer.Play();
        dt.Start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible, ugly, workaround:

```
video_timer = new System.Threading.Timer(x=>refresh_video(), null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1 / 60.0));

private void refresh_video()
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate() { MediaElement1.InvalidateArrange(); });
}
```

Since it works i will go with this but i'd really love a better solution.

Comment: Did you get anything less ugly in the end? I am having this problem too and it seems a rather basic bug for a media element.

Comment: No, unfortunately that's actually the part of code deployed with the application to the store.

Comment: I will admit I am confused how to implement the above, could i be very cheeky and ask a for a pastebin showing the surrounding code?

Comment: It actually creates a timer to forcedly refresh the video each frame. You create the timer when the video is unpaused and stop it when the video is over. The refresh_video method just needs to be in-scope.